# Snapper fails to list snapshots

Tags: snapper

I'm having a strange problem with this [snapper](http://snapper.io/documentation.html) command:

```
snapper -c home ls
```

The error is:

```
IO Error (open failed path:/home/.snapshots errno:2 (No such file or directory)).
```

However, `ls /home/.snapshots` shows that the directory exists. Furthermore, it is populated with current hourly snapshots. So snapper is able to write snapshots, but it cannot list them.

`snapper --verbose -c home ls` provides only the same limited error info.

The following command succeeds:

```
snapper -c home create -d testing -c timeline
```

And this verifies the snapshot is in the expected location:

```
ls -lat /home/.snapshots/
```

Yet this command still fails with the error listed above:

```
snapper -c home ls
IO Error (open failed path:/home/.snapshots errno:2 (No such file or directory)).
```

I'm running:

Arch Linux
snapper 0.7.1 (flags btrfs,lvm,ext4,xattrs,rollback,btrfs-quota,no-selinux)
btrfs

Comment: same here, could you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, I have not solved it yet.

Comment: I opened and issue https://github.com/openSUSE/snapper/issues/449